# RegEx: Find word after a letter but don't include the letter in the result

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

Here's a string that I may have:

```
(MyStringIsOneWholeWord *)
```

I have used the following javascript regular expression to get the text after the bracket if it starts with `My`.

```
/(^|\s|\()+My(\w+)/g,
```

The problem with this is that it includes the first bracket in the result, as that it is the letter/character that found it.

How would I get rid of the bracket in the result?

---

**EDIT**

For more information, I am editing the `C Language` javascript file of the SHJS syntax highlighter.

Here's all the relevant code for this question:

```
[
 /(^|\s|\()+My(\w+)/g,
 'sh_keyword',
 -1
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this was *just* JS you could use a capture group:

```
/(^|\s|\()+(My\w+)/g
```

Then get the match at that group. However, it appears that SHJS will use the entire match, requiring the use of lookbehind, which is not supported by Javascript's Regex engine.

---

To get around this, I'd suggest you to [read the documentation](http://shjs.sourceforge.net/doc/documentation.html). This part here:

> Once you have defined the language,
>   you must convert it to the JavaScript
>   format used by SHJS. You will require
>   the sh2js.pl script from a source
>   distribution of SHJS. The sh2js.pl
>   script is written in Perl and requires
>   the Parse::RecDescent module.

Tells me that the resulting JS files aren't meant to be edited. The docs say SHJS uses the same format as GNU Source-highlighting, which is specified [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/source-highlight.html#Language-Definitions). So you should be editing the original [`.lang` (link)](http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/lang_files/c.lang) files and then converting them to `.js`.

Comment: Neither of them work for me unfortunately, it won't even do what it did before. :/

Comment: That still doesn't work for me, but now you pointed out that the string may have something do with it. This is the actually string, not sure whether or not it would affect it though: `(MyStringIsOneWholeWord *)`.

Comment: `*` is also not included in the character class `\w`. Try modifying the regex to `/(?:^|\s|\()+(My\w+)\W/g`

Comment: Still no luck with that either.

Comment: @Joshua Please post the rest of your code. I am sure these work.

Comment: Also, what exactly do you want to capture if the input is `(MyStringIsOneWholeWord *)`, `MyStringIsOneWholeWord` or `MyStringIsOneWholeWord *`?

Comment: Updated my original post and I am trying to capture `MyStringIsOneWholeWord`.

Comment: Hmmm, I see. So it's a combination of SHJS and javascript's restrictions. Thanks for the information. :)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a *positive lookbehind assertion*.  Unfortunately, Javascript doesn't support them.  However, Steven Levithan covers this in a blog post here: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript

Edit: Updated article by same author: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/javascript-regex-lookbehind

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think the OP can use any of these workarounds. Interesting link though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what exactly you want to capture, but you can try some of these :

capture `StringIsOneWholeWord` in $1 :

```
/(?:^|\s|\()+My(\w+).*\)/
```

capture `MyStringIsOneWholeWord` in $1:

```
/(?:^|\s|\()+(My\w+).*\)/
```

capture `MyStringIsOneWholeWord *` in $1:

```
/(?:^|\s|\()+(My\w+.*)\)/
```

capture `StringIsOneWholeWord *` in $1:

```
/(?:^|\s|\()+My(\w+.*)\)/
```